# Several questions on the mean value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

Fisrt here is the theorem :"Let $f : [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on the closed interval $[a, b]$, and differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$, where $a < b$. Then there exists some $c \in (a, b)$ such that : $f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$".

So first, if $\lim \limits_{x \to a}f(x)= -\infty$ and  $\lim \limits_{x \to b}f(x)= +\infty$ does this theorem work ? If it does why ?

Second, if we substitute $[a,b]$ to $\bar {\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$
does the theorem is equal to the first form ? ($\bar {\mathbb{R}}$ is a compact set.)

Thanks in advance.

**PS** : I try to prove some generalizations of this theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ and $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=f(b)$ are never equal to $\pm\infty$.

For the second question, if $[a,b]=[-\infty,\infty]$, what is $(f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)$?

In the case where we can make sense of it, the result is not true in general. Consider for example $f(x)=\arctan x$. Then $f(\pm\,\infty)=\pm\,\pi/2$ and it is reasonable to set $(f(a)-f(a))/(b-a)=0$, but $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: if $[a,b]=[-\infty,+\infty]$ it tends to zero if $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are finite.

Comment: Then see the example in my answer.

Comment: Ok I see so the theorem does not work for $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ ?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Thanks and if $f: \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ does the theorem work ?

Comment: How do you define $f(b)-f(a)/(b-a)$?

Comment: It is the same problem as $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ ?

Comment: Similar, but on this case it is not clear how the quotient is defined.

Comment: If I define $\Psi : \bar {\mathbb{R}} \rightarrow \bar {\mathbb{R}}, x \mapsto (f(a)-f(b))x-(b-a)f(x)$ with $a=-\infty, f(a)=f(b)=+\infty, b=+\infty$ then I get $\Psi(a)=\Psi(b)=af(b)-f(a)b=-\infty -\infty=-\infty \in \bar {\mathbb{R}}$ which exists. Then I can apply Rolle's theorem on $\Psi$. This is what happens for $x\mapsto x^2$ for instance.

Comment: $f(b)-f(a)=\infty-\infty=$?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to interpret $b - a$ and $f(b) - f(a)$ if $a = ± ∞$, $b = ± ∞$, $f(a) = ± ∞$ or $f(b) = ± ∞$ in order to make sense of the theorem.

This will be cricital for e.g. $f = x²$ on $[-∞..∞]$ (or $f = \mathrm{tan}²$ on $[-π/2..π/2]$) as then “$f(a) - f(b) = ∞ - ∞$”.